# How to automatically convert sub- super-indices to strings?

Tags: string-manipulation, syntax, subscript

Consider the following expression:

```
expr = "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(t\)]\)"
```

I would like to convert it to the ordinary string e.g. `"m_t"` which may be used as e.g. a filename, but

```
expr // ToString
```

does not work properly. Could you please tell me how to convert it?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to string"? It is already a string. Please show us what the expected output is.

Comment: @Domen : when exporting it as a filename it gets wrong.

Comment: Try [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html).

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you really want the filename to be "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(t\)]\).txt" or whatever extension with all the backslashes and the glob * that will probably cause trouble down the line. (If you want it to be something else, you haven't said what.)

Comment: Cool. I get a filename with a subscript. Didn't expect that to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vohDC.png Of course it displays that way only in Mma. But maybe I'll start using Mma as my file browser.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this?: `Export["/tmp/" <> StringTrim[ToString[expr, InputForm], "\""] <> ".txt", "foo"]`

Comment: @JohnTaylor, again, you did not provide an example of the output. Please do this. Do you want it to be converted to what MichaelE2 suggests? Do you want it to be "m_t"? Do you want it to be "mₜ" (namely, using Unicode [Subscript Small Letter T](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+209C), however note that [only a few](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2070) letters are available)?

Comment: @Domen : I have modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you get something like `expr` in the first place? It's probably much easier to produce "m_t" from a step earlier in the process. Anyway, from [@Edmund's suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290051/how-to-automatically-convert-sub-super-indices-to-strings#comment721701_290051):

```
ToString["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(t\)]\)", TeXForm]

(*  "m_t"   *)
```

Alternative from an imagined earlier step:

```
ToString[Subscript[m, t], TeXForm]

(*  "m_t"  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example,

```
expr = Subscript[m, t];
ToString[expr[[1]]] ~~ "_" ~~ ToString[expr[[2]]]
```

does the trick. For a more complicated example, perhaps the following should also work:

```
StringReplace[ToString[expr, CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"], "\n " -> "_"]
```